# Bash Linux: Sorting by prioritizing special characters than alphabetical characters

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I would like to sort the below input file, according to the 8th substring, which starts after the 8th char "/" (substring "svc..."), BUT I want within the substring to prioritize 1st the character ":", 2nd the character "/" and lastly the alphabetical characters.

Any suggestion, how can I achieve this using sort? Or any other ideas?

**Input file**:

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb:
```

**Desired output file:**

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc/log:
```

***So far, I have tried these, but still no the desired result:***

```
cat input.txt | sort
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb:

cat input.txt | sort -t : -k 1,1
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb/log: 

cat input.txt | sort -t / -k 9,9  
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svca:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb/log: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcba: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbb: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc/log:
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcbc: 
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/path6/ser/svcb:
```

Comment: Not exactly.
In my special case, I want to sort in alphabetical order, but if I find chars ":" and "/", I want to give them higher priority.
So for eg., if I had these 3 substrings: "a", ":" and "/"
I would like this result sequence: ":", "/", "a"

Comment: Please show the code of your best attempt and explain what's wrong with it. Then , somebody will maybe help you with **your** code.

Comment: @wasilis By providing the field separator, the fields' values no longer contain it, so the values of the fields sorted by will be prioritized automatically.

Comment: You can `tr` the `:` and `/` to some control character (ascii<=31) that you are sure does not appear in the txt and then `tr` it back after sorting. BTW with the priority request I don't hink it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: With `tr ':/' $'\x1e\x1f' < in | LC_ALL=C LC_COLLATE=C sort | tr $'\x1e\x1f' ':/'` I can get your expected output. However I cannot post an answer since the question is closed.

Comment: Top!
It works exactly as I wanted!
Thanks!

Comment: Unfair that your answer is not posted.

Comment: Those how voted to close have been a bit too fast on this. The answer they point to is **not** an answer for this specific question that requires one form or another of transform-sort-transform. Voted to reopen.